# Oracle Database XE - setting SID during installation

Tags: oracle, oracle18c

Is there any possibility of changing the default SID of Oracle Database during installation from RPM? I want to do this without X-Window-System. I want to do this during configuration - when i invoke this command:
`/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure SidParameter`
i want to give SID as a parameter.

Comment: Why? The System Identifier (SID=XE) will serve any SERVICE_NAME you like. Database clients (java,go,npm,python) can all connect something like this:  user/pass@hostname:1521/MY_SERVICE_NAME.

Comment: But when I'm using two databases with the same SID for Delphix virtualization it causes a problem.

Comment: Are you sure you need two separate Database Systems (SIDs) on the same host? You can separate your data by schema or by pluggable database (multitenant architecture > 11g). One Oracle Database System (RDBMS) (SID=XE) can serve data for ALL your applications.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. I can't do this without SID change.

Comment: Ran into the same problem, couldn't find a solution. Works with the standard or enterprise edition, of course. It should be possible to change the SID after installation, though.

Comment: It is possible to change SID after installation, but I actually don't know how to do this. I have been trying to do this for almost a week.